# How to make sound waves affect values?

Tags: audio

Is it possible to make sound waves (loudness) affect another parameter such as Multiply, Saturation, Glow, etc. of other strips? It's something like a visualized sound wave, yet the result I want is glow (on a picture) to increase when the sound gets louder, and glow to decrease when it's quieter.

**EDIT:
I accidentally stumbled upon a way to solve it! It's called "bake sound to f-curves".**

EDIT #2:
Is it possible to adjust the levels of the baked curves? I can go as far as a value of 1 when the sound is maxed out in Audacity. I can decrease the threshold by lowering the volume in Audacity as well, but there's no way to go beyond that. Maybe there's a way to do that in Blender itself? You see, not all the Blender effect values go only from 0 to 1. Sometimes it needs a negative value, sometimes - a dozen.

**EDIT #3:
Yeah, figured it out. It's done by adding a Noise modifier to an F-Curve, and selecting Multiply for the Blend Type.**

Comment: If you find the answer to your own problem, please post the answer down below the question in the "Your Answer" box.  No need to include the answer in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add a key frame to a property. You can then proceed to use bake sound to f-curves.

See https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/editing.html#bake-sound-to-f-curves

Comment: Please add the information given at the link to your answer, and make it clearer *how* to do what you suggest for future readers. This will greatly improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Yeah it was midnight, and I thought people would be smart enough to look up the quoted sentence, as it's a way to find it on Youtube.

Though I have another thing to solve, maybe you know?